# I only want to display the matching users up until the comma

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, solaris

I want to print the color along wit the users who match, not all the users.
So I want to find bob and riley and only print the data associated with them and not the other users. If there is no matches I would like the whole line just to be skipped and not display anything

How can I achieve this?

```
awk '{ FS=":"; print $1 " " $4 }' /test|while read color person
do
   if [[ `echo ${users}|egrep -i "bob|riley"` ]]
   then
   printf " ${color} - ${person}\n\n"
   fi
done
```

used FS because in the file there are 4 field separated by the ":"

Input looks something like this:

```
red: :car:todd,riley,bob,greg                 
green: :jeep:todd,riley,bob,greg,thomas                                                    
black: :truck:jamie,jack,bob,travis,riley
```

Output currently:

```
red - todd,riley,bob,greg
green - todd,riley,bob,greg,thomas
black - jamie,jack,bob,travis,riley
```

Desired output

```
red - bob,riley
green - bob,riley
black - bob,riley
```

Doesn't have to be sorted like this but it would be helpful

Comment: What's the exact logic that takes you from input to output?

Comment: Please add that to the question so it's self-contained, instead of having the information spread across question and comments.

Comment: What would happen for a line where no name matches? Would it be skipped, or would it look like `blue -` and then nothing?

Comment: @BenjaminW. ok.  I  would like it to be skipped if no match.

Comment: Do the names have to be sorted? In your examples, the order isn't preserved from input to output. PLEASE add all these details to the question.

Comment: ok sorry i will @BenjaminW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have GNU grep available, you can use option [`-o` (--only-matching)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002do)

```
echo ${person} | egrep -o -i -e "bob|riley"
```

will show for the first line

```
riley
bob
```

Now you can combine the results with [`tr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1p.html)

```
echo ${person} | egrep -o -i -e "bob|riley" | tr '\n' ,
```

gives

```
riley,bob,
```

And finally strip the trailing comma

```
echo ${person} | egrep -o -i -e "bob|riley" | tr '\n' , | sed -e 's/,$//'
```

which results in

```
riley,bob
```

Comment: Would the  -o still work if the input was something like "jbobsmith"

Comment: Yes, "jbobsmith" will be found too, but only the "bob"-part will be printed. So for printing the whole name, you must modify the search pattern.